# My Excel crashes whenever I run this simple VBA sub

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Highlight_Diff()  
    Dim i, j As Integer  
    i = Starting_Row
    Do While Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""
         For j = 1 To 2 * Currencies
            If Abs(Cells(i, 3 * (3 * Currencies + 1) + j).Value) > 100000 Then
                Cells(i, 3 * (3 * Currencies + 1) + j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
             End If
         Next j
    Loop
End Sub
```

Note Currencies and Starting_Row are just constant integers. As you can see all I am trying to do is loop though rows of code and higlight particularly large balances (for context this has to do with discrepancies which arise due to exchange rate differentials). When I try running this simple sub, my Excel crashes... every single time. I tried running it in a module instead of workbook but that didn't work either. It's definitely not because there are two many rows (only a few hundred, and only 4 cells per row as currencies is set to 2 for this particular job). Any idea on how I can fix this?
*NOTE: Yes I did have i = 1 instead of j = 1 in my for loop at first but I fixed this and it still crashes, so that doesn't appear to be the problem.

Comment: You use `i` twice in different loops. This question is not useful to future generations....

Comment: Begin by setting **i** and **j** to *Long*

Comment: integer can only hold upto +32767

Comment: He uses `For i` and `Next j`

Comment: @RobinMackenzie  that.can't be good.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an error here : `i` is always reset to 1 at the beginning you the main loop since you also use it in the `for`.

```
Do While Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""
    For i = 1 To 2 * Currencies
        If Abs(Cells(i, 3 * (3 * Currencies + 1) + j).Value) > 100000 Then
            Cells(i, 3 * (3 * Currencies + 1) + j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next j
Loop
```

Since you use `next j`, I beleive you intended to use that, so change the `'i'` in the `for` for a `'j'` and see if it works

If it's the source of your problem, you may be witnessing an infinite loop.

---

As pointed by cyboashu you might also need to use a `Long` since vba Integers only count up to `32767` and down to `-32768`

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is always looking at the same value.

Since `i` is no longer a looping variable (in the corrected code) you are left with the following while loop:

```
Do While Cells(Starting_Row, 3).Value <> ""
   ...
Loop
```

You aren't changing the value of Starting_Row, and you aren't changing the value in the cell.

Either you (1) never execute the Do-While code or (2) you execute it forever.

I expect you forgot to increment `i`

See if this works:

```
Sub Highlight_Diff()  
    Dim i, j As Integer  ' better practice to make this type a Long
    i = Starting_Row
    Do While Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""
         For j = 1 To 2 * Currencies
            If Abs(Cells(i, 3 * (3 * Currencies + 1) + j).Value) > 100000     Then
                Cells(i, 3 * (3 * Currencies + 1) + j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
             End If
         Next j
         i = i + 1 'moves you to the next row until empty cell is found
    Loop
End Sub
```